# Reinstall missing network drivers that used to work

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, ubuntu-drivers

## The problem

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04. It was working fine. Last time I shut it down when I came back to my computer and turned it on, I was unable to connect (I tried using wifi, Bluetooth and USB) I can't try ethernet.

## What I tried

I checked if it was a hardware related problem by booting in a different system (an other Ubuntu version that lives on the same computer) and it worked perfectly fine

I tried troubleshooting using this tutorial https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting-hardware-check.html.en and it seems to be a driver related problem which is logical since I was able to use the same hardware to connect in the other system but I couldn't find a fix for my specific driver in that tutorial and didn't dig deeper as I want to try the solution below

## What I want to try

I am tempted to use my live USB that I used to install the os for fixing this issue but I don't know what to do there

## Additional information & question

Earlier this week, when I shut down my computer then up, I had a big problem with my gnome-desktop and was forced to reinstall it. Could these two problems be related or is it just a bad week?

## EDIT (4 days later)

The weirdest thing just happened, I haven't logged in this machine since last time (the day of the original post where I tried rebooting many times with no success) and now ... I opened it and it just works ! I'm not trusting it will continue to work but I am unable to understand what is going on !

Comment: Check in terminal `dpkg -l | grep linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)`

Comment: `ii  linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-44-generic       5.8.0-44.50~20.04.1                                       amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP`

Comment: If it ever happens again, run that same command and see if no results show as that package contains the wifi/bluetooth/other drivers.  You will likely need to use grub to boot into an older kernel to install that package

Comment: Thank you this will be truly helpful